# Get total sum for in Sql server for unknown location?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

There is an `insurance  policy` and this policy can be paid by `1-3 agents`.

[image]

line #1 ) for example : for policy Id `1` ,  an agent **who's ID** is `100` , paid `123`

line #3 ) for example : for policy Id `3` ,  an agent **who's ID** is `999` , paid `741` , and also another agent who's ID is `100` paid `874`

*(the representation is `not` how it should be done correctly , but that how I have it as  a fact).*

How can I found how much agent ID `100` has paid **total** ?
(123+541+874+557+471+552)

*I have a very ugly union's solution.*

**[SQL ONLINE](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/edit/93494)**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a well normalized model this is a simple query. You can 'normalize' in a CTE query then sum:

```
with cte as (
  select agent1id as id, agent1sum as s
  from insurance where agent1id is not null
 union all
  select agent2id as id, agent2sum as s
  from insurance where agent2id is not null
 union all
  select agent3id as id, agent3sum as s
  from insurance where agent3id is not null
)
select sum( s)
  from cte
 where id = 100
```

This is a friendly index approax if your table contains index for agents columns. A friendly index query avoid full table scan.

Comment: Wht do you mean _friendly index query_ ? over agent1id , agent2id ,agent3id  ?  The table will actually will be scanned 3 times...

Comment: DB optimizer will transform 'human readable query' to an internal access plan. If agents fields are indexed a full table scan will be avoided.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like

```
SUM(
   CASE WHEN agent1id=100 THEN agent1sum ELSE 0 END +
   CASE WHEN agent2id=100 THEN agent2sum ELSE 0 END +
   CASE WHEN agent3id=100 THEN agent3sum ELSE 0 END)
```

should aggregate it properly. If you need to do it for all agents, I'd use the agent table or use a CTE before this query to get the distinct agent IDs, then replace 100 above.